# Reformat Data in Excel Using Formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formatting

I have some Raw Data that I need to reformat as shown in the picture attached. I have also included a link to the file I am working on. The file has formulas in the Output section. I need help getting the layout in the Desired Output section in the excel file. (Credit: @Prema for the initial assistance and formulas)

Ultimately, I need to get only one row if two rows in a section, for example in cells B6, C6, D6, and E6 the same as B7, C7, D7, and E7 only show B6, C6, D6, and E6. Then the cost and discount price for that row for January, February, March, etc. for B6, C6, D6, and E6.

There are some instances where the matching values as described above are within a section for one person, for example for John, but they are separated by another row with different values. This means B6 thru E6 matches B8, D8, C8, D8, E8.

Any help you can provide is appreciated.

[Raw Data and Desired Output Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9AZM.png)

[Link to Excel File](https://enthyco-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/p/tydavis/EWX-WQGE3vBKsEP9LziSFl8BxVBfpN2GTQOoGzhak2Insg?e=cmRIZI)

Comment: This looks like it should be a pivot table?

Comment: Please try to take a look at this video, it gives you several options on how to handle this: [3 Ways to Switch Data in Columns to Rows in Excel (Multiple Values)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8HakuTeijGI&list=PLmHVyfmcRKyxoMlFsXyiDVy9xQa9JfoJK)

Comment: @pgSystemTester I wish it was that simple...

Comment: @DavidLeal Thanks for the video link. I'll watch it attentively to see if it will be the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following approach uses *Pivot Tables*. Based on your example and the way you want to show the information organized it seems to be a reasonable option.

[image: output of the Pivot Table]

*Pivot Tables* have some format limitations (merge, wrap columns) so in order to visualize better the information I selected short names for example **Discount** instead of **Discount Price**. Because the source of the *Pivot Table* has the **Cost** column, you can not name it in the same way, so I changed the name of the original column to **Cost Item**.

Here is the source table of the Pivot Table:

[image: source of the Pivot Table]

This is the *Pivot Table File List settings* (the look and feel varies from Excel version and operative system, this is the look and feel of Excel Web):

[image: pivot table configuration]

Because you don't need total/subtotals, and the look and feel is a tabular format, such options are not selected:

[image: Pivot table settings]

You don't want to show the expanse/collapse buttons, then unselect the corresponding option:

[image: Unmark expanse/collapse]

It is difficult to show all the steps in an answer, because you can have have several options and configurations and it is a visual tool. I assume you have a basic knowledge on how to use *Pivot Tables*, if that is not the case, please check some video tutorial on internet.

Here you have [link](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlZxw2GG3C7Ih0a99mw1yjapIYvO?e=iB5SoJ) to the sample file used in this answer, so you can understand it better.

Comment: I didn't realize this could be accomplished using a Pivot Table and humbly retract my earlier comment... First, thanks for laying this out and providing the sample file. In the event that there are two rows with duplicate data that are separated by a row with different data, will the Pivot Table combine those regardless? For example, the data in row 5 remained and the matching data in row 6 was in row 7.

Comment: Thanks for providing the solution and for your guidance. The output is exactly what I need.

Comment: David, I added the Grand Total row for the Cost Item and Discount Price Item columns, and am trying to find a way to sum the respective values in the Grand Total row. The challenge is when the raw data volume changes the Grand Total row initially referenced also changes. For example, the initial Grand Total row is 30, then the data changes, and the new row number changes to 28. Do you know of a way to make the reference to the Grand Total row dynamic so that when it moves the Cost Item and Discount Price Item values will get updated?

Comment: @Ty. I added grant total by row and by column in the link I shared with you I don't know if that is what you are looking for. I am using Excel for Web and this is the only configuration I see we can do. Check the file

Comment: I saw this option to turn it on for rows and columns, though wanted to have the summed grand total for each at the top. I think I'll turn it on for rows and columns, and use it as is. Thanks again!